# Python Open CV canny is detecting everything but the edge

Tags: python, opencv

Canny Is detecting edges everywhere except the road. 
Here is the original image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjekZ.jpg

Here is a sample image. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjNag.jpg

I have already tried playing around with Canny thresholds. 
And applying a GaussianBlur, medianBlur ,bilateralFilter,

I also have attempted to use a black and white image threshold fitter first but the problem is that terrain slightly changes colors and that causes problems.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time

def screen_record(): 
    last_time = time.time()
    while(True):

        # record upper left corner of screen to get the image. 
        printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40,1098,728)))
        print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
        last_time = time.time()
        color = cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        canny = cv2.Canny(color, 20, 100)
        cv2.imshow('edges',canny)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

screen_record()
```

I expect to have just one solid line. 
Like image Below. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R8R9.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use opening and closing operations together to filter the noisy edges in `canny`. The code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('vLnzxEs.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 20, 100)

# visualize the canny image
plt.figure
plt.imshow(canny, cmap='gray')

#decleare kernel for closing and opening operations
kernel = np.ones((75,75),np.uint8)
# apply closing and opening
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(closing, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# visualize the opening 
plt.figure
plt.imshow(opening, cmap='gray')
```

The output looks like

[image: that]

Answer (score 1):

computers don't "see" things the way humans do!  assuming you care more about detecting the "road" than why the Canny filter isn't "working" I'd just compare the red to the green channel, that gives very good separation (in this type of image) between roads and grass.  e.g:

```
img_bgr = cv2.imread('road.png')

delta = img_bgr[:,:,1] - img_bgr[:,:,2]
delta = cv2.blur(delta, (200, 200))
road = delta > 128
```

gives me:

[image: road]

i.e. `True` values (white) are road, `False` values are grass.  this should be much easier to interpret than "lines" from canny.

this will of course do strange things in other locations, but might be enough to get you started

Comment: what do you mean "plot code"?  the image is a result of `cv2.imwrite('road_out.png', road.astype(delta.dtype) * 255)` if that's what you mean.  otherwise you could use matplotlib to do `plt.imshow(road)`